# have any way to change tag name dynamically in get query ?

Tags: ghost-blog, ghost

{{#get "posts" filter="tag:news" as |news_post|}}

{{#foreach news_post}}

{{title}}

{{/foreach}}

{{/get}}

#### How Can I Change "news" tag dynamically ?

Comment: I believe you should use API. I found that link for you to use API https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/creating-a-post-archive-with-the-ghost-api-and-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

By your question I suggest you want to base it on some that within your .. post perhaps ? You can use it within the `{{post}}` by using the `{{tags.[0].slug}}`

```
{{#get "posts" filter="tag:{{tags.[0].slug}}" include="tags" as |news_post|}}
    {{#foreach news_post}}
        - {{title}} - {{tags.[0].slug}}<br>
    {{/foreach}}
{{/get}}
```